# Logarithms: How do you isolate $x$ in $2\log(x)=\log(4x+5)$

Tags: logarithms

I'm having trouble isolating x when

$$2\log(x)=\log(4x+5)$$

I tried distributing and adding the logs, but is it even possible to distribute logs?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note $2\log(x) = \log(x^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this type of equation, you should aim towards getting $\log a = \log b$, and then concluding that $a = b$ based on the one to one nature of the logarithmic function.

Also $\log x^n = n\log x$ is nice to remember.

After this step, solve the quadratic. Remember to check for validity of the solutions in the original equation.

Whatever you do, *don't* fall into the elementary trap of trying to split up the logarithm of a sum. Remember, $\log (c + d) \neq \log c + \log d$ in general. The correct statement is $\log cd = \log c + \log d$. I just mentioned this so you don't fall into a common trap. You don't actually need this property here.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I didn't give away the answer. Instead I took the trouble to write a lengthy answer that only guides the OP to a solution. That's what teaching is all about. And whoever downvoted this is clearly against teaching or guiding anyone else in this fashion. I wonder if they really belong on a site that's supposed to be about helping others.